# Latest angular2 form

Tags: forms, angular

I have a angular2 version debounce input control, template like below.

```
<input type="text" [ngFormControl]="compInput" placeholder="demo input" />
```

In my component.ts

```
import {Component} from "angular2/core";
import {Control} from "angular2/common";
@Component({
 ...
)
export class Demo{
  private compInput = new Control();
  constructor(){
    this.compInput.valueChanges.subscribe(() => {});
  }
}
```

these code works until I upgrade my angular2 version to latest.
It seems form usage has changed.

I changed **[ngFormControl]** to **ngControl** and **Control** to **FormControl** from "@angular/forms", but doesn't work.

Does anyone know where I am wrong about the new usage and how to fix?

Comment: What error message do you get?

Comment: no error, just won't work when I type in the Input control.

Comment: Are you sure you "updated" everything? Because it should be `import {Component} from "@angular/core";`

Comment: And `Control` from `@angular/form`

Comment: Please also add how you initialize the new form (bootstrap).

Comment: yes, I have added the @ symbol

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer， I didn't get it, the code in the question is all I have, others is no difference with angular2 Quickstart

Comment: Your question seems about the new forms but you don't seem to use the new forms at all. For an example how to use the new forms see https://plnkr.co/edit/9XogrULe6atg4WMOCiqS?p=preview (see also `bootstrap()` in `main.ts`) (not the best example but couldn't find a better one, but it shows how to enable the new forms).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all your help. I have find the answer for my question with help of my colleague. Here it is.

**template.html**

```
<form #form="ngForm">
  <input name="nameInput" [(ngModel)]="componentName" #nameInput="ngModel">
</form>
```

**component.ts**

```
import {Component, ViewChild} from "@angular/core";
import {NgModel} from "@angular/common";

@Component({...})
export class Demo{
  @ViewChild('nameInput') nameInput:NgModel;
  componentName:string;

  ngAfterViewInit(){
    this.nameInput.update  //or this.nameInput.control.valueChanges
     .subscribe((val:any) => {console.log("value update", val);})
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple example using ngModel

```
import {Component, Input, Output, HostListener, EventEmitter, ChangeDetectionStrategy} from '@angular/core';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import {Subject} from 'rxjs/Subject';

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'user-search',
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
  template: `
    <form role="search">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input
          class="form-control"
          name="input"
          type="text"
          placeholder="Search user"
          [(ngModel)]="input"
          (keyup)="keyup$.next($event.target.value)"
        />
      </div>
    </form>
  `
})
export class UserSearchComponent {

  input: string;

  keyup$ = new Subject<string>();

  @HostListener('window:keyup', ['$event'])
  cancelSearch(event) {
    if (event.code === 'Escape') {
      this.input = undefined;
      this.keyup$.next(undefined);
    }
  }

  @Output() search: Observable<string> = this.keyup$
    .debounceTime(700)
    .distinctUntilChanged();

}
```